# how to download a full directory listing?

Tags: download

I need to download a full directory tree (and subfolders of course) in HTTP

https://cours.etsmtl.ca/gts840/laboratoires/

I want all the stuff in the directory instead of downloading one by one. Which download manager supports that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget)

```
  wget -m https://cours.etsmtl.ca/gts840/laboratoires/
```

Answer (score 1):

[GNU wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/)

```
wget --mirror https://cours.etsmtl.ca/gts840/laboratoires/
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
wget -m --no-check-certificate https://cours.etsmtl.ca/gts840/laboratoires/
```

The second option ignores SSL.